# Fragment in main activity returns null fragmentmanager.findviewbyid<>

Tags: android, xamarin

I have created the `MainNavigationDrawerFragment`.

However, when I try to `findviewbyId` , both the `drawerFragment` and `drawerlayout` returns `null`, when I try to set up drawer.

Since this activity is the main launcher, through the `fragmentmanager.findviewbyID()`, I would expect it to kick off the fragment `onCreateView` event so that I can inflate the fragment. Howerver, it's returning null.

Any help?

```
public class ProfileView1 : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ProfileView2);
            // other code....

            // Navigation Drawer
            SetUpDrawer();
        }

        private void SetUpDrawer()
        {
            **MainNavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment =
                FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MainNavigationDrawerFragment>
                                                        (Resource.Id.nav_drwr_fragment);

            DrawerLayout drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>**(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);**
            drawerFragment.SetUpDrawer(Resource.Id.nav_drwr_fragment, drawerLayout, toolBar);
        }
```

> /////////////////////////This is the
>   layout///////////////////////////////

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        layout="@layout/ToolBarOnlyLayout"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarProfile" />
    <include
        layout="@layout/ProfileMainPageLayout"
        android:id="@+id/profileMainPageCardView" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recentSearchRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_drwr_fragment"
        android:name="UserProfile.Fragments.MainNavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/navigationdrawer_main_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/navigationdrawer_main_fragment"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: What's the declaration of `MainNavigationDrawerFragment`? Are you by any chance using the `SupportFragment` base class? If yes, you'll have to use `SupportFragmentManager` to access it.

Comment: You can also find an example of inflating a `DrawerLayout` here: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/android5.0/Cheesesquare/MainActivity.cs *Note:* they are using `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment` for support.

Comment: MainNavigationDrawerFragment inherist from fragment and inflates the fragment layout. Inorder to get to the MainNavigationDrawerFragment  I need to instantiate the fragment in mainactivity(prifileview1)

`MainNavigationDrawerFragment : Android.support.v4.Fragment
{}`

Comment: I also tried using supportfragment manager but did not work. The other strange think is why does drawerlayout not return anything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I solved it. There are 2 issues here. I had to change the layout to not use android:name but class instead.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_drwr_fragment"
        *class="UserProfile.Fragments.MainNavigationDrawerFragment"*
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/navigationdrawer_main_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/navigationdrawer_main_fragment"/>
```

The second part is that i had to use supportfragmentmanager since my fragment uses support.app.fragment

```
 drawerFragment = (MainNavigationDrawerFragment)this.SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.nav_drwr_fragment);
```